# TL494 Based buck boost converter not working properly

Tags: power-electronics, mosfet-driver, switching, buck-boost, tl494

I was working on the buck-boost converter using the [TL494](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl494.pdf?ts=1703737468450&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) IC. The requirement is 5-50V output 10A  fs=70k approx, Vin=15V. Initially, I had used a PMOS irf9450 for the switching. The simulation worked fine but as I moved to the hardware, I was getting a very large amount of current taken out from my external 15V supply. The mosfet got very heated and I wasn't getting my desired voltage.

[image]
I thought maybe the gate of the MOSFET is not driven perfectly and PMOS requires a good gate to source voltage otherwise it will always be turned ON. For this purpose, I had to go for the NMOS irf540N. Now in this case I practically made it on a breadboard but my circuit wasn't working. The circuit is shown below where the op-amp basically does the conversion from the negative to positive voltage. Here the circuit works fine. For the demonstration, I used a fixed feedback divider instead of a variable.
[image]
I was not getting the desired voltages practically as the opamp didn't give me accurate values at the feedback pr practically. In order to just test the circuit without feedback I added a potentiometer at the feedback pin. The duty cycle changed perfectly but now in this case on adding a load of even 10k on it at the output the mosfets and all the jumper wires on the breadboard started to heat very much, such that I could see the wire insulation melting. Altough I was getting an output but the conditions were worse.
[image]

1. Kindly help me figure out the error in the schematic. Is the opamp in the feedback a correct way to convert the negative voltage to positive??
2. I feel like adding mosfet drivers could help me as the IC may not properly drive my mosfet. The datasheet of [TL494](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl494.pdf?ts=1703737468450&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) used transistors but I used mosfets.
3. What is the reason for such a heating of the MOSFET? I don't have the circuit image right now but the setup was done on a breadboard and some jumper wires.

Comment: Why use pull-ups AND pull-downs on MOSFETs? And pull-downs on the PMOS too?

Comment: That's the requirement for the IC. Which increases the duty cycle on the output with an increase in voltage on the FB pin. So we want that as the voltage outside drops then the duty cycle should increase. For this to occur I have done the following

Comment: No, I know the basic function of the TL494, I know how open-collector/emitter outputs work. The question was why *both*, the pull-downs (mostly) are overridden so why put them in? The intent seems to be "because they always show it", but then why also on the PMOS where it pulls it towards default-on?

Comment: You could try to have a look [here](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/high-power-inverting-buck-boost-converter-circuit-design-with-tl494) but the TL494 might not be the simplest circuit to work with for such a converter. A UC384x could be a better choice with a high-side driver like I described [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491419/how-to-reduce-mosfet-heating-in-buck-converter/491437#491437) on SE.

Comment: @VerbalKint I have done almost the same but am not getting the desired results. Can it be the issue of driving the mosfet or not?

Comment: @TimWilliams I dont know if I got your question completely but using a single mosfet didnt worked for me because this made the feedback a positive one by getting a much higher duty cycle on increasing voltage on feedback. The PMOS was a good choice as it provides me with this using a single MOSFET. On getting high it basically allows no current flow in the circuit.

Comment: Well, you could check at the junction of the MOSFET and the inductance which should be at \$V_{in}\$ during the on-time and swing negative during the off-time. If you don't have \$V_{in}\$ - or close to it considering turn-on drop - then something is wrong with the drive.

Comment: @VerbalKint is the rest circuit fine? The feedback with an opamp in between?

Comment: Did you check the gate pulses with scope? Are they sharp enough? 500 ohm for charging gate seem too slow for me. Is the mosfets turned on/off completelly? Do not it stays in linear a bit?

Comment: @MichalPodmanický yes I checked, the pulses were not that sharp and were somewhat like the waveform of a charging capacitor. But still it was greater than the threshold voltage.